# Asynchronously sending file to server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Browser side: js function

```
function insertDocFile(file) {
    var id=@Model.Id;
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append(file.name, file);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.open('post', '/Hike/UploadBlog/' + id);
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Input parameter 'file' is file for sending to server.
Server side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult UploadBlog(int id)
    {
            HttpPostedFileBase fileData = Request.Files[0];
            return View()
    }
```

But Request.Files count is 0.

The file  is not sending to server. A few weeks ago, this code works great. But at one point it stopped. I did not make any change. What may be due to this error.What could be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel and writing low level code, why don't you take advantage of a library such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that abstracts some of those details for you?

Comment: Did you try the Developer console(F12) in browser while sending file to server? Any error?

Comment: With jQuery Ajax the same result.

Comment: POST http://localhost:6972/Hike/UploadBlog/24 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you use something like 'var streamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();'  Then get each file by looping the `streamProvider.Contents` and read the byte array.  Not sure if this applies in mvc4 but it works nice in mvc5

Comment: object Request does not contain 'Content' in MVC 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I sent .doc file larger than 70 MB. Such files are not sent in this way. It is necessary to divide it on the client side, send parts and assembled on the server.

Thank you for your help.